# How to use a variable from a loop multiple times in a sql statement in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, teradata

I've got a list in pandas that I want to iterate through, and for each item in the list, apply it to multiple components of a SQL query

Below is what I've been trying to work with, but I don't get anything back in the results, which makes me think that the variables aren't populating correctly.

If I run the SQL query outside of python, with a single hardcoded value, it works.

What am I missing?

```
import teradata
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

start_date = "2017-10-28"
stop_date = "2017-10-30"
mydates = pd.date_range(start_date, stop_date, format='%Y-%d-%m')
date_list = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in mydates]

data = []

for x in date_list:
    for row in session.execute("""
    select distinct CAST(? as DATE)as dateId, count(*) 
    FROM tableA
    where last_date>=?-365 and first_date>=?-360
    group by 1""", (x, x, x, )):
        data.append(row)
```

Comment: Are you using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: In Teradata you can simply use the alias instead:`where last_date>= dateId-365 and first_date>= dateId-360`

Comment: @EricEdLohmar I'm using PyCharms as the IDE and edited the above with the packages I'm using

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for the suggestion, running it now

Comment: @dnoeth you're suggestion worked! Thank you, it's funny how sometimes we think too hard for a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a parameter placeholder, `?`, in any numeric operations, `+ - * /`, and the same for string operations (i.e., concatenating wildcards operators to `LIKE` expressions).

Therefore, simply run your operations before binding values to prepared statement in the *params* argument of `con.execute` or `cursor.execute`. Also, the comma ending inside a tuple is not needed for multiple items only for one-item tuples.

```
import datetime as dt

start_date = dt.datetime.strptime("2017-10-28", '%Y-%m-%d')
stop_date = dt.datetime.strptime("2017-10-30", '%Y-%m-%d')

rng = (stop_date - start_date).days

date_list = [(start_date + dt.timedelta(days=i)).strftime(format='%Y-%m-%d')  
             for i in range(rng+1)]    
last_date_list = [(start_date + dt.timedelta(days=i+365)).strftime(format='%Y-%m-%d')  
                  for i in range(rng+1)]    
first_date_list = [(start_date + dt.timedelta(days=i+360)).strftime(format='%Y-%m-%d')  
                   for i in range(rng+1)]

strSQL = """select distinct CAST(? as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') as dateId, count(*) 
            from tableA
            where last_date >= cast(? as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
              and first_date >= cast(? as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            group by 1"""

for x, l, f in zip(date_list, last_date_list, first_date_list):
    for row in session.execute(strSQL, (x, l, f)):
        data.append(row)
```

Comment: This definitely could work, but you might want to expand your example a little bit keeping OP's data types in mind or using `datetime` with the `date` and `timedelta` instead of `pandas` if `pandas` is not necessary.

Comment: Good point! Edited accordingly where OP can `zip()` through needed lists for query and params.